# Combining the results of two SQL queries

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have data in two tables and I need in one query get all data and join getting data.

```
SELECT 
kpip.PersonalName, 
kpiT.Name, 
kpiPR.KpiTarget, 
kpiPR.KpiResultDate, 
kpiPR.KpiResult
        FROM KpiPersonalResult AS kpiPR join KpiPersonal as kpip 
        on kpiPR.KpiPersonal = kpip.Id join KpiType AS kpiT 
        on kpip.KpiType = kpiT.Id join MerchantAdministrators as merA 
        on kpiPR.KpiAdded = merA.Id and kpiPR.KpiResultDate between '2021-04-07' and '2021-04-08' 
        
        select 
                kpiP.PersonalName, 
                kpiT.Name, 
                kpiP.KpiTarget 
                        from KpiPersonal as kpiP join KpiType as kpiT 
                        on kpiP.KpiType = kpiT.Id
```

Comment: You need to show some sample data, your expected results, and explain how exactly you want to combine the data. Have you considered `union all`?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the fast that the second query has 3 columns of the same name as the first query, I guess you mean to union them:

```
SELECT 
  kpip.PersonalName, 
  kpiT.Name, 
  kpiPR.KpiTarget, 
  kpiPR.KpiResultDate, 
  kpiPR.KpiResult
FROM 
  KpiPersonalResult AS kpiPR 
  join KpiPersonal as kpip on kpiPR.KpiPersonal = kpip.Id 
  join KpiType AS kpiT on kpip.KpiType = kpiT.Id 
  join MerchantAdministrators as merA on kpiPR.KpiAdded = merA.Id and kpiPR.KpiResultDate between '2021-04-07' and '2021-04-08' 

UNION ALL

select 
  kpiP.PersonalName, 
  kpiT.Name, 
  kpiP.KpiTarget,
  null, --put suitable default values for the other columns here
  null 
from
  KpiPersonal as kpiP 
  join KpiType as kpiT on kpiP.KpiType = kpiT.Id
```

Unioned queries need the same number of columns. I've inserted NULL as default value for the two missing columns in the second query (relative to the first)

UNION makes a resultset grow taller. If you intended for it to grow wider, that is done via JOIN. A simple pattern for doing so is:

```
WITH query1 AS(
  --query 1 here
), query2 AS (
  --query2 here
)
SELECT * FROM query1 JOIN query2 ON ...
```

Side note  on formatting and indenting - most people find SQL most readable when all operations that are related are at the same indent level e.g in a typical query, the SELECT FROM WHERE GROUP ORDER keywords are all at the same indent level, with the blocks that relate to them (the list of selected columns, or list of joined tables, list of where'd predicates etc) indented a level again. We also typically don't use `as` when aliasing tables but we do use it when aliasing columns in the SELECT

Comment: Bro how to not allows to duplicated data from my combined list?

Comment: Use `UNION` alone rather than `UNION ALL`, or reconfigure the queries so that they do not select duplicated data. You should remain conscious that UNION performs a dedupe by a reasonably intense operation - if you can stop duplicates at source rather then trying to remove them after, it may be better for performance